# How do I return a selected value from a complicated dropdownlist in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

My dropdownlist works like a treeview.  Since, I cant seem to figure out if Html.DropDownListFor does this, I am having to do it the old fashioned way.  Here is my code.

View:

[image: View]

Controller:

[image: Controller]

How do I get the selected value (LocationId) back to my controller?  id="locSelection" in the view, brought in as object selection in the controller.  Thank you:)

Comment: Although I edited to make the images visible, please edit to directly include code (not in image).

Comment: I have vision issues. So that I can read the code, can you paste it as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all it's not a old fashioned way it's the bootstrap way of replicating dropdown
- Second of all it's not a drop down element...

Since this contains only `ul` and `li` tags and those are not of input type you cannot post back the values...

Also another problem in the code is you are setting the ID `locSelection` on multiple elements and that too in a loop .. So you will have a whole lot of elements with the same ID which is a Big **NO**. The Id's must be unique else it's a nightmare when we start using Jquery on these elements...

**Solution -- Use Jquery**

- Remove the Id's
- Add a class to all the anchor tags eg: `locSelection`
- Maintain a hidden input field inside your form. We will use this hidden input field to post back the data on form submit.

`<input type='hidden' name='locSelection' id='locSelection' />`

- Now bind a click event to the anchor tag inside the `li` and inside this event put that Clicked anchor tag text value into the hidden input.

`$('.locSelection').on('click',function(){
  $('#locSelection').val($(this).text());
});`

Comment: Thank you Reddy.  That has helped a lot.  I'm a winforms guy that is experiencing MVC for the future.  It is quite different.

Comment: @John Glad I was helpful :)